# Export to csv after loop ends with powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have the following powershell scripts that iterates through all list items and workflows, trying to find old running workflows

The logic is OK, but I need to be able to export to to csv with the columns
ListeItemUrl, ListItemName, Nr of Days Opened.

```
$web = get-spweb https://mysite.com/sites/billing
$list = $web.Lists["Bill Cycles"]
$count = 0
foreach($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
{
   if ($wf.Name -like "*Previous Version*")
   {  
      Write-Host 'Bill Cycles with old workflow: ' $wf.Name  
      foreach($listitem in $list.Items)
      {

        if($listitem.ContentType.Name -eq "Bill Cycle")
        {
            $workflows = $listitem.Workflows
            foreach($Workflow in $listitem.Workflows)
            {
                if($Workflow.AssociationId -eq $wf.Id)
                {
                    $count = $count+1
                    Write-Host $listitem.Name
                    Write-Host 'https://mysite.com/sites/billing/'$listitem.Url.TrimStart();
                    Write-Host 'Workflow opened for: ' ((Get-Date) - $Workflow.Created).Days
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
Write-host 'Count: ' $count
```

Then with the exported file I can easily sort by nr of days and deliver the report I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your output as a csv - *ListeItemUrl, ListItemName, NrofDaysOpened* - and pipe it to `Export-Csv` cmdlet( you can find out more by running `get-help Export-Csv`). You will have to change *Write-Host* to *Write-Output*

Comment: that will create one file per loop, I need one file only

Comment: There are few ways you can overcome that. Make sure you position your export-csv cmdlet in the right place, pipe your output to a variable and then at the end of your script pipe that variable to `export-csv` or run entire script(assuming it's called _script.ps1_) as follows:  

`.\script.ps1 | expor-csv C:\somepath\file.csv`